# how to refresh the fragment when tab is reselected , MaterialTabHost

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tabs

I am using MaterialtTabHost and ViewPager and i want that whenever i switch to new tab it should be updated with new data automatically.

This is my activity in which i have added the tabs and viewPager for every ViewPager i have a different Fragment to show.

```
public class FrontPage_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialTabListener {
    ViewPager mPager;
    StorageUtil storageUtil;
    User user;
    MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    MyPageAdapter myPageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        for (int i = 0; i < myPageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText(myPageAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page_);
        storageUtil = new StorageUtil(this);
        storageUtil.setUserStatus(1);
        user = storageUtil.getUser();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (user != null)
            actionBar.setTitle("Welcome " + user.getName());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        myPageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(myPageAdapter);
        /*for (int i = 0; i < myPageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTab().setText(myPageAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }*/
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                } else if (position == 1) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String tabs[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return setFragment(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    private Fragment setFragment(int number) {
        if (number == 0) {
            Chats chats = new Chats();
            return chats;
        } else if (number == 1) {
            Request frag = new Request();
            return frag;
        } else {
            Invite frag = new Invite();
            return frag;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chatting_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                storageUtil.clear();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this could be a bit tough, one approach has people different result also, yet there are eventually some ways to put on test.

One approach I usually used is to override the *getItemPosition*.

In your custome adapter (*`MyPageAdapter`* ), override *getItemPosition* like so:

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 ...
  @Override
      public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
         if (object instanceof Chats ) {
            ((Chats )object).updateMyLogicOrView();
         }
         if (object instanceof Request) {
            ((Request)object).updateMyLogicOrView();
         }

     if (object instanceof Invite) {
            ((Invite)object).updateMyLogicOrView();
         }
         return super.getItemPosition(object);
      }
..
}
```

Then on each fragment which belongs to its own tab, You create *`updateMyLogicOrView()`*. In the method, you put down some operations you want that supposedly to generate new data / update data on the view. When you move to a tab, this *updateMyLogicOrView()* will always be invoked through the overriden method.

```
// put this method on each fragment class
public void updateMyLogicOrView(){
 // do some logics here..
// like component.setText()
// or, adding some new elements to adapter..

}
```